# Equality operator in D3DXVECTOR3 class

Tags: floating-point, directx, equality-operator

```
D3DXVECTOR3::operator == ( CONST D3DXVECTOR3& v ) const
{
    return x == v.x && y == v.y && z == v.z;
}
```

Above is `==` operator of `D3DXVECTOR3` class in `D3DX10math.h`

According to what I know, use `==` operator directly in float can cause a problem, but MS give that code.

Is it OK to use it directly? No problem? Why?

Comment: Using == operator directly in float does not cause any problems, however it is often used in situation when strict comparison is not appropriate.

Comment: Keep in mind that legacy D3DX math is deprecated as is the rest of D3DX9/D3DX10/D3DX11. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-). Use [DirectXMath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dxmath/directxmath-portal).